# How to pass object from one thread to another without using state object

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, .net-4.0, log4net

I have an ASP.NET application which uses a component in an class library assembly to make web service calls. The component uses the Thread Pool or some sort of home brewed threading solution to spawn background threads in which synchronous web service calls are made.

A logging component is used in the ASP.NET application and by helper classes that the component calls from the background threads spawned when it does service calls.

In ASP.NET a HttpModule creates logging context object and stores it in the HttpContext.Current.Items collection. The helper classes used in the ASP.NET application and in the helper classes fetch the logging context object from HttpContext.Current.Items when a message needs to be logged in order to decorate the logged message with information that puts the logged message into a context.

When the helper classes are called directly from ASP.NET, HttpContext.Current is available.

When the helper classes are called from background threads created by the component, HttpContext.Current is null and so there is no logging context available to them when messages are logged; the logged messages are useless.

I don't have control over the component which creates the threads for making service calls. If I did, I would arrange for the logging context obect to be copied and passed into the child thread.

My logging context object cannot be static, because it would be overwritten by concurrent ASP.NET request threads and that would be bad.

The members of my logging context object (simple int/string properties) could be marked ThreadStatic, which would work, and I would not need to use HttpContext.Current.Items anymore.

What I really need is a to make the .NET runtime copy the object (or even pass a reference; either would do) and makes it available to child threads automatically.

I was wondering whether I could add a <system.threading> element to web.config and nominate a helper class for creating threads like you can do for Web Requests in %lt;system.net>

I also wondered whether I could mark my Logging Context object with some attribute that causes it to be copied automatically.

I looked into log4nets LogicalThreadContext, tried it, but it didn't work. I think that's for passing logging context information across processes or appdomain boundaries.

What mechanism does log4net's LogicalThreadContext used behind the scenes? Something from System.Runtime.Remoting? Is that deprecated now?

My environment is .NET 4, so maybe with the parallel extensions or enhancements to threading in .NET 4 this is now possible.

Anyone any idea if this is at all possible? I'm beginning to think not.

- Update *

I have had to do the following:

```
Task<IEnumerable<Account>> accountsTask = Task<IEnumerable<Account>>.Factory.StartNew
    (
        instrumentationContext =>
            {
                var parentContext = instrumentationContext as Site.Instrumentation.InstrumentationContext;
                if (Site.Instrumentation.InstrumentationContext.Current == null && parentContext != null)
                    Site.Instrumentation.InstrumentationContext.Current = parentContext;
                return GetAccounts();
            },
        Site.Instrumentation.InstrumentationContext.Current
    );
```

Where the GetAccounts() method calls on another class which in turn depends on Site.Instrumentation.InstrumentationContext.Current

The problem is, I would rather NOT have to change the code to explicitly pass in and set this state object in the child thread - I want the .NET Framework to do that for me automatically, so that the code (above) that creates the task is none the wiser and does not have to be changed.

If no-one else contributes with alternatives, Jon gets the green tick as I figured that was my only realistic choice albeit with tasks not threads.

Comment: Post some code to understand what you are doing and trying to achieve. Its really hard to put together all of your question at once in one's head and make suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly all you need to do is to pass an object to a thread signature so what's wrong with a parameterized thread start ??

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object j = new object();
       Thread t = new Thread(()=>childThread(j));
       t.Start();
    }

    private static void childThread(object someObject)
    {
        // do work
    }
```